# how to get the number from this class element?

Tags: javascript

The timer goes from 40 to 0 and the script should wait till there are just 100 miliseconds and press a button.

How can I get that number so it will be x = 14.22 *1000-100?

I know I need to delete te letters but how ?

Plese just javacript, no jquery!

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
var run = document.getElementByClassName("button1");
setInterval(function() {

    var time = document.getElementByClassName("Timer h4").innerHTML;
    var x = time * 1000 - 100;

    setTimeout(function() {
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        run.dispatchEvent(evt);


    }, x);

}, 15000);

function x3a() {

    document.getElementById("x3").innerHTML = 1;
}

<h4 class="Timer h4">Time expire in 14.22</h4> //how can I read this number 14.22 so I can use it?
<p id="x3"></p>
<button data-g="red" class="button1" onclick="x3a()">OK</button>
```

Comment: Why would you read that value from the HTML rather than using some JS value for both your timer and the HTML?

Comment: `var time = time .replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '') ` will give you string as "14.22" then do `parseFloat(time)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick up the `h4` element, and use a regex to match against the numbers.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('h4');
const txt = el.innerText.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0];
console.log(txt);
```

```html
<h4 class="Timer h4">Time expire in 14.22</h4>
```

Comment: it works in a compiler but when I run it in a page it just doesn't read the value and el is 0, so document.querySelector('h4'); doesn't work in a browser

Comment: Make sure your script is just before the `</body>` tag. The script has to wait for the DOM to load before you can access it.